# How to direct users for enabling accessibility service for my app

Tags: android, accessibility

I know It's impossible to enable the Accessibility service for apps programmatically, so I'd like to direct users to this screen:
`System settings` --> `Accessibility` --> `app name` --> `enable/disable screen`. 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get them to the Accessibility screen on most devices [using `ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS). However:

- that may not work on all devices, so you will want to just send them to Settings as a fallback, if you get an `ActivityNotFoundException`
- there is no way to get them straight to any given app, let alone the enable/disable screen

Answer (score 1):

You can at least make it reach the app, making the app item blink. It should work for most devices, or at least those that are like of Pixel devices:

```
    fun <T : AccessibilityService> getRequestAccessibilityPermissionIntents(context: Context, accessibilityService: Class<T>): Array<Intent> {
        var intent = Intent("com.samsung.accessibility.installed_service")
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) == null) {
            intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS)
        }
        val extraFragmentArgKey = ":settings:fragment_args_key"
        val extraShowFragmentArguments = ":settings:show_fragment_args"
        val bundle = Bundle()
        val showArgs = "${context.packageName}/${accessibilityService.canonicalName!!}"
        bundle.putString(extraFragmentArgKey, showArgs)
        intent.putExtra(extraFragmentArgKey, showArgs)
        intent.putExtra(extraShowFragmentArguments, bundle)
        return arrayOf(intent, Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY))
    }
```

Usage:

```
    private fun requestAccessibilityPermission() {
        getRequestAccessibilityPermissionIntents(this, MyAccessibilityService::class.java).forEach { intent ->
            try {
                startActivity(intent)
                return
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
        }
        //TODO do something here in case it failed
    }
```