# How to create an Android app that can capture the global touch screen events when user is playing with another app?

Tags: android

As the title said, in my research I need to log user touch screen events, mainly gestures(such as tap, scroll, swipe, etc) when a user is using another app. Currently I can't figure out a good way of doing it. It seems that for Android 4.x the touch screen events can not be read out? Anyone knows any good methods to capture the touch events?

Comment: Does [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and/or [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) not suffice?

Answer (score 5):

I was also doing R&D from quite some time to get global touch events inside an ANDROID App.

Actually our requirement was to capture touch coordinates on phone  from inside ANDROID app.

We tried several approaches:

1- First we tried to put a transparent  layout(like a layer of glass on above the phone screen)    which covers the phone screen and then receive the touch events and dynamically removing the glass so that the event could be passed to below the glass and then dynamically inserting the glass again.
But the drawback was that it require two times tap which is not feasible (because 1st tap would give the touch coordinate  and second touch would be passed below the glass).

2- Then we tried to use one special flag in window manager i.e. flag_watch_outside_touch by making the transparent layout size 1 X 1 but we were getting touch coordinates as (0,0)  because Android Framework imposes security that no other process can get touch points inside other process.

3- Then we tried to run command "adb shell getevents" through code but it was not accepting touch events (although by using "adb shell sendevent"   we were able to se send global touch events i.e. by passing a coordinate we were able to pass event on particular coordinate on the device screen.

4- Now we were quite sure that without rooting no App can get global touch events that will happen on some other app process. Android security will not allow this otherwise any app can passwords or other user input data.

But.... we have to do this (without rooting) ...

5- Now we tried to use shell script and executed the getevent command from command prompt and redirected the touch events to a file  and parsed the touch events to get readable coordinates ..

So we cannot capture global touchevents inside an app through code but yes we can capture from OS level by executing getevent command from adb shell.
That we can the pass to android app by storing it into external storage inside phone storage .

Hope this will help you all.

Thanks,

Comment: hi @amarnathpatel, I am currently developing an app with similar requirements as you describe here. My question is regarding 5) point of your post: Did you manage to run `adb getevent` **inside** Android process, or triggered it on PC's (or server's) command prompt? If yes, is the root access, or debugging turned on, needed for this to work? What I've found in my current research is that adb is not a part of Android system. In order to run it from application I would need to compile its sources with my app. I hope I will reach you with this comment and you will be keen to share your knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible due to security and privacy reasons (as Sir SC mentioned) unless you're rooted.

I have tried multiple things (even asked a question on Stackoverflow: [Android - Inactivity/Activity regardless of top app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882331/android-inactivity-activity-regardless-of-top-app)). I came to the conclusion that using an "Accessibility Service" is the closest we can come to knowing when a user has touched the screen. This isn't fool proof, however. You will not get an event for every screen touch (scrolling in Chrome didn't yield any events).

---

With that said, if your application can rely on a rooted solution then it's possible to listen to incoming lines from `getevent` (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/getevent.html). These lines simply give details of touch (and other) events. But this requires root access so it might not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: then how does teamviewer app record touch events in background?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should already found this one but it "may" be the only library which can help you on this since you *can't* interact between activities directly because of security and privacy reasons:

[GitHub android-global-touchevent](https://github.com/kpbird/android-global-touchevent)

Comment: This GitHub project helps you add a View on screen, when you ca alwyas listen to touch events ON THAT VIEW. But it's not really a Global Touch event service

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether to post this as a comment or an answer, but I suspect that this should not be possible due to security concerns. If you could monitor activity in another application like that without it being obvious to the user, you could inappropriately monitor password enteries into other applications. For that reason I wouldn't be surprised if that sort of activity is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As amarnathpatel said its almost impossible to get touch events without root.But there is an workout through which we can get events but not the co-ordinates.It is done using FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH.
[check this out](http://jhshi.me/2014/11/09/monitor-screen-touch-event-in-android/index.html).