# Android: Is there a way to simulate click through and actions to automate things?

Tags: android, apk

It has been a super long time since I last coded anything for Android.

Anyways, I have a number of apps which I get free stuff. For example the Google Play points we get each week.
I can't find an app to just help automate some of this. So I'm thinking about making an app which more than less reminds you and send you to the proper app when you press the notification.

I wonder if I can automate it even more. Is there a way record your actions, and then use that to get the app to do it on request?
Like for example the Google Play thing. Where when you press the notification or whatever button. It will follow the steps you took exactly. This making it where if you have daily rewards from multiple places. You can press a button, wait a few minutes, and that is that.

I'm just trying to figure out if Android even lets you run this. I know a few years back Google went heavy handed which ran off apps like Cerberus. Like they are doing some privacy stuff. So I wanted to check if it is possible before wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform actions on another app by recording them in your app.

It is very possible but not the easy way. The only possible solution I understand is to train a Deep Learning model that detects user actions and save them. Then you can perform same actions with the help of OpenCV through your app. For that you have to screen record the app and pass the recording to Deep Learning model to detect user actions.

Also look on this question for better understanding
[Capture the global touch screen events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221595/how-to-create-an-android-app-that-can-capture-the-global-touch-screen-events-whe)

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's a bit more than what my skill level allows for.